# How and when is copy of pointer made

Tags: c++, c, pointers

In the code below output is coming 20 and explanation is given that inside `fun()`, `q` is a copy of the pointer `p`. So if we change `q` to point something else then `p` remains unaffected. What is the mechanism of function making copy of pointers.
Why `p` is not printing 10 when it stores the address of `q`.

```
void fun(int *p)
{
    static int q = 10;
    p = &q;
}   

int main()
{
    int r = 20;
    int *p = &r; 
    fun(p);
    printf("%d", *p);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inside `fun()`, `q` is a local integer. `p` is a parameter to the function that is effectively ignored; the local copy of `p` is made to point to `q`, but this information is then unused because the function returns.  If you wrote (inside `fun()`) `*p = q;`, then you would assign 10 to `r` (and `*p`) in your `main()` function.

Comment: How and why is local copy of p made and why "p is a parameter to the function that is effectively ignored"

Comment: When a function is called in C, the arguments are passed by value; a copy is made of some value.  In the case of `fun(int *p)`, the value is the value of a pointer; in the calling code (confusingly), you have `int *p = &r; fun(p);`, so a copy of the pointer value stored in `p` from `main()` becomes the initial value of the local variable `p` in `fun()`.  You ignore the value that is passed to `fun()` by immediately overwriting it with the address of `q`.

Comment: "how and why...?" The parameter list declares local variables in the function, which could have the same names as other variables in the program. If you want there to be a single `p` variable, declare at the top-level (outside any function), and don't pass it in as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function `fun` pass arguments by value. If you want to modify variables outside the function, you need pointers. Since you want to modify a `int *` pointer outside the function, you need a `int **` pointer:

```
void fun(int **p)     //here
{
    static int q = 10;
    *p = &q;
}   

int main()
{
    int r = 20;
    int *p = &r; 
    fun(&p);        //and here
    printf("%d", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

In C++, you can use pass-by-reference in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

"if we change q to point to something else" -- q does not point, it is not a pointer. It is an integer.
If what you meant is "If we change q's value" such as by

```
q = 12
```

Then two things happen.

- p does not change, because it still points to the location of q (it is an address)
- *p does change, from 10 to 12, because *p means "value at"

  Finally "why is p not printing 10"

The p in your main function is different from the p in your "fun" function.  They start off with the same value, since you pass it (fun(p)) but when you change it (p  = &q) you are changing the  p in fun, not the p in main.  So p remains pointing at &r (not &q) and so *p is 20

Answer (score 0):

> explanation is given that inside fun(), q is a copy of the pointer p

No. The `p` in `fun` is a copy of the `p` in main.

> So if we change q to point something else

`q` is not a pointer. You can't make it point to something else, or point to anything at all.

> What is the mechanism of function making copy of pointers.

The argument in the function call:

```
fun(p); // this p here
```

is copied to the parameter in the function definition:

```
void fun(int *p) // this p here
```

> Why p is not printing 10 when it stores the address of q.

Because `p` doesn't store the address of `q`. At least, not the `p` in main, who's dereferenced value you are printing. Only the `p` in `fun` points to `q`. But that is a local variable to the function, and you are not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different variables, both called `p`.

One of them is declared in `main()`, the other in `fun()` (the variables declared in the parameter list are local to the function). They don't conflict because they are local variables in different functions, but it does look confusing.

Note that the same code would be produced is the references in `fun()` were called `pp` instead of `p`, but you wouldn't be confused to thinking them the same variable.